# spark groupby driver throws OutOfMemory

Tags: apache-spark

I have a RDD[((Long,Long),Float)] about 150G (shown in web ui storage).
When I `groupby` this RDD, driver program throws following error

```
15/07/16 04:37:08 ERROR actor.ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-39] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1188)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply$mcV$sp(Serializer.scala:129)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$toBinary$1.apply(Serializer.scala:129)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.toBinary(Serializer.scala:129)
        at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.serialize(MessageSerializer.scala:36)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:845)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:845)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.serializeMessage(Endpoint.scala:844)
        at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.writeSend(Endpoint.scala:747)
```

The executors didn't even start the stage.

This RDD has 120000 partitions. Could this be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The size of a at least one of the partitions is more that the memory you have allocated to the executor (you can do that with the `--executor-memory` flag on the command line running the spark job

Comment: Hi I don't quite understand why it is an executor runs out of memory? Cause it says [sparkDriver].

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by (Long, Long), at least one of your groups are big to fit in memory. Spark expects each record after grouping ((Long,long), Iterator[Float]) to fit in memory. and this is not the case for your data. see this https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/tuning.html look for **Memory Usage of Reduce Tasks**

I suggest to have a work around by increasing your data parallelism. Add a mapping step before the group by and break down your data.

ds.Map(x=>(x._1._1,x._1._2,x._1._1%2),float))

Then group by the new key (you might do something more sophisticated than this x._1._1%2).